# Two eyes; one at the start / the other at the end

Tags: riddle

This is one I created:

> Two eyes; one at the start,
>
> the other at the end
>
> each meeting a shimmering wall
>
> yet when you look in one
>
> you see through the other

I guess it's kinda obvious but it's cool anyway.
So, what is the answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While there are many answers that could be suggested for this, the one which (to me) seems to fit the wording best is:

> a **periscope**:
>
>  [image: Periscope image, from Wikipedia]
>
>  (Specifically one relying on internal *mirrors* rather than prisms...)
>
>  This has two 'eyes' (openings), one at each end, beyond which you find a mirror ('a shimmering wall'), and when you look through one end you see out of the other.

Comment: Yes! Exactly! (And I did not think about prisms)

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer possibly be

> a telescope?

Comment: No shimmering wall, but good try!

Answer (score 0):

One wild guess:

> The Illuminati

```
Two eyes; one at the start,
the other at the end
```

> Two 'i's obviously.

```
each meeting a shimmering wall
```

> Illuminati literally means illuminated.  It could shimmer

```
yet when you look in one
you see through the other
```

> Hmm... could mean these Illuminati all look alike.